# How to convert a map<string, string> to map<string,float) in pig

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I have a `udf` that returns a `map{string, string}`. Now I want to save this map as `map{string, float}`.

In my statement, I have

```
results = foreach data generate udf(params) as field:map[float];
```

Now `udf` returns a `map{string,string}`. This is throwing exception like cannot cast string to float. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: could you show the relevant parts of you UDF?